# createPattern doesn't work with ImageBitmap in Safari?

Tags: javascript, canvas, safari

According to the documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createPattern, ImageBitmap is a supported argument, and Safari is claimed to have full support.

However, trying to substitute a canvas element with ImageBitmap in the provided example, it fails with some mysterious TypeError on Safari, but works fine in other browsers.

I can't find anything on this issue, is it a browser bug or something is missing from the documentation?

```js
// Create a pattern, offscreen
const patternCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const patternContext = patternCanvas.getContext("2d");

// Give the pattern a width and height of 50
patternCanvas.width = 50;
patternCanvas.height = 50;

// Give the pattern a background color and draw an arc
patternContext.fillStyle = "#fec";
patternContext.fillRect(0, 0, patternCanvas.width, patternCanvas.height);
patternContext.arc(0, 0, 50, 0, 0.5 * Math.PI);
patternContext.stroke();

const bmp = createImageBitmap(patternCanvas);

bmp.then(bmp => {
  // Create our primary canvas and fill it with the pattern
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const pattern = ctx.createPattern(bmp, "repeat");
  ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // Add our primary canvas to the webpage
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
 });
```

Comment: Yep that's a browser bug. Weird thing is that WPT has tests that should catch this. Though in that exact case you don't need the ImageBitmap (I guess that's just for the repro case). Maybe using an intermediary bitmaprenderer canvas might provide an acceptable workaround, though I didn't test yet.

Comment: I modified the example from MDN article to use ImageBitmap so yes it's not needed in this case, but my actual code uses it to construct bitmaps directly from a blob, and most of the images are used for regular draw operations so having all of them use HTML Image instead is probably not ideal. Do you know if Safari has a bug tracker similar to chromium? Apple seems to only provide a simple bug report form.

Comment: Yep that's https://bugs.webkit.org/ I understand your pain, and I still didn't have time to look at this myself, but what I'd try in your position is: write a test (since it throws that should be as easy as `const test = async () => { const ctx = document.createElement("canvas") getContext("2d"); const bmp = await createImageBitmap(ctx.canvas); return ctx.createPattern(bmp, "repeat"); }` and then if this rejects, you use a secondary canvas just to render the ImageBitmap, and use that secondary canvas as source in your `createPattern()`.

Comment: But since ImageBitmap is the main image source in workers and that Safari is bringing support to OffscreenCanvas, I'd expect they will fix that soon enough. You may even want to check if they have an issue open already.

Comment: Here it is: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=149986